# No keyboard layout in keyboard preferences to match Danish macbook

Tags: keyboard-layout, macbook, preferences

Some critical keys (@) are in accessible on my Macbook running Natty. It's a 2006 danish keyboard model. Is there a way to edit the layout without resorting to Terminal? Alternatively where could the right layout be found? (it's not in keyboard prefs. i tried them all)

thanks for the answer below my keyboard looks like this:

[image]

the danish layout on Ubuntu misses the function key. the problem is that i cant get to the 3rd and 4th levels of the other keys.

Comment: Could you provide a picture of your keyboard? Have you tried to make some adjusts in layout options?

Answer (score 2):

Is your keyboard something like this?:

[image]

If the answer is "yes", than you will be able to fix the @ issue by running something like this on terminal:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  11 = 2 quotedbl 2 quotedbl twosuperior at twosuperior at"
```

Comment: Nope. Look at the `@` symbol.

Comment: I don't have a Mac. If there isn't an exact match of keyboard but there is one with only a few keys wrong, then these keys could be fixed with the command above. This is a workaround until some wise can post some more acceptable solution.