# Danish Mac keyboard layout isn't correct

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mac, keyboard-layout

No matter which one of the 5 available Danish keyboard layouts I choose from, the `@` symbol (at) is always <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> instead of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd>, which is normal on Danish Mac keyboards.

The answer to [No keyboard layout in keyboard preferences to match Danish macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56952/no-keyboard-layout-in-keyboard-preferences-to-match-danish-macbook) doesn't fix this.

List of Danish keyboard layouts in Ubuntu:

[image]

`Danish (Macintosh)` keyboard layout in Ubuntu:

[image]

Danish keyboard layout in Mac OS X (no modifiers, shift, alt, alt+shift):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If there is not an easy way to fix this without manually changing all the keys, could I use the following text to automate this?

```
1:              $1234567890+´
2:              qwertyuiopå¨
3:              asdfghjklæø'
4:              <zxcvbnm,.-

SHIFT-1:        §!"#€%&/()=?`
SHIFT-2:        QWERTYUIOPÅ^
SHIFT-3:        ASDFGHJKLÆØ*
SHIFT-4:        >ZXCVBNM;:_

ALT-1:          ¡“§£∞™¶[]≠±'
ALT-2:          °∑é®†¥ü|œπ‘~
ALT-3:          ªß∂ƒ©«‹∆¬äö@
ALT-4:          ≤Ω…ç√∫ñµ‚·–

SHIFT+ALT-1:    '¯”$¢‰˜\{}≈¿⁄
SHIFT+ALT-2:    •˚ÉÂ‡ŸÜıŒ∏’^
SHIFT+ALT-3:    Êˇ˘ﬁÁ»›˝ﬂÄÖº
SHIFT+ALT-4:    ≥¸˙Ç◊ËÑ˛„÷—
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit (2021-04-11):**

After having to setup a Macbook with Ubuntu again (almost 8 years after asking this question!), I created [`dk_mac_fixed-layout`](https://github.com/Tyilo/dk_mac_fixed-layout), which fixes some keys.

---

**Old answer:**

By searching `launchpad.net` I found several bugs about this.

One of the people mentioned a fix, with the instructions here: http://howto.praqma.net/ubuntu/keyboard

This keyboard is not exactly the correct Danish MacBook keyboard layout, but it is much better than the one that comes with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue that must be fixed by Canonical. I do not see how I could offer a fix. It may be an issue with the localization and/or the Apple hardware support for Ubuntu. Try submitting a bug report to Canonical by going to Launchpad.net. Find Ubuntu, and then report this bug. Include a link to this page so the developers can see your descriptive images. I am sure they will take your problem very seriously.